# Open android service or activity on boot api 29

Tags: java, android, background, android-service, boot

this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.openboot">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".StartAppOnBoot" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My `BroadcastReceiver` that "receives" the boot completed intent:

```
public class StartAppOnBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

My `MainActivity` that I need to open:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I need `MainActivity` to open when the phone turns on, but I don't see the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   Intent intent = new 
   Intent(getApplicationContext,StartAppOnBoot.class);
   sendBroadcast(intent);
  
}
```

reference
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#java

Comment: This only works when MainActivity is opened. This calls the BroadcastReceiver and BroadcastReceiver calls MainActivity... Don't solve the problem.

Comment: The application must be open and the system closes the application is forced. There are restrictions from the Android Oreo version, and after that, in using the service, you can turn on notifications that make the user that the application is running in the background. 
 https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background